# How does ShowWindow report failure?

Tags: windows, winapi

Reading the documentation it looks like the [`ShowWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx) function has no notion of failure. This surprises me since it seems that pretty much any non-trivial code can fail.

The window handle might be invalid. Clearly, that's a contact violation committed by the caller but is this case simply "undefined" or "don't care", then?

I wonder if `SetLastError` is supported.

Comment: `::SetLastError( 0 ); if( ! ::ShowWindow( 0, SW_SHOW ) ){ DWORD err = ::GetLastError(); std::cout << err; }` ... prints 1400 (ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE)

Comment: Just noticed that the `if ( ! ::ShowWindow(...` is crap, because as documented, the return value of `false` just indicates if the window was previously hidden, not if an error happened.

Comment: What about `SetWindowPos( hwnd, nullptr, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER )` ... it has a BOOL return value and officially supports `GetLastError()`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

ShowWindow does not have any error-awareness. If the window provided does not exist (or is not accessible), it just returns false.

ShowWindow in fact does not do much more than sending a WM_SHOW message to the targeted window. Because of the nature of the windows message queue, ShowWindow has no knowledge about its completion status. Although, as pointed out in the comments, WM_SHOW is handled synchronously, the message queue itself has no built-in error reporting mechanism aside from sending error messages back to the sender.

[edit]
It seems that GetLastError reports an invalid window handle when trying to access a non-existing window. To me, this is an unknown behaviour as normally a return value should indicate whether to use GetLastError or not. However, this can be easily avoided by testing for the window manually in advance (see: IsWindow)

Comment: No. Messages are not always async. SendMessage for instance is synchronous. WM_SHOW is not an asynchronous message. It is not queued. The second paragraph is quite wrong.

Comment: Actually it seems to support `GetLastError()`, which returns 1400 (ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE) if the window does not exist. Empirical test under Win 10.

Comment: That's different from my experience (long time ago) when I ran into the same problem. Maybe they changed the behaviour?

Comment: @zett42: That's not *"support"*. That's coincidental evidence, not part of the documented contract. It may or may not work, for an undisclosed set of versions of Windows, using any one of an unlimited number of system configurations. Unless explicitly documented, the return value of `GetLastError` is meaningless.

Comment: @Psi: `GetWindow` is the wrong tool to verify validity of a window handle. Use [IsWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633528.aspx) instead. Doing so exposes an obvious TOCTOU race condition, so the check doesn't buy you much in terms implementing a solution that's guaranteed to work. Besides, `SendMessage` does have a return value, pointer-sized, and can return arbitrary error information.

Comment: @zett42: [Don’t just stand around saying somebody should do something: Be someone](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110118-00/?p=11733).

Comment: `SetWindowPos` might be a valid alternative that avoids race conditions, see my comment under OP post.

Comment: _ShowWindow in fact does not do much more than sending a WM_SHOW message_ ... not true. You propably mean `WM_SHOWWINDOW`, but this isn't a substitute for `ShowWindow()`. The message only has a BOOL parameter for changing the visibility state, but `ShowWindow` can do much more, e. g. maximize/minimize a window, showing a window without activating it, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

While `ShowWindow()` indeed has no notion of error, we can use `SetWindowPos()` as an alternative that is documented to support `GetLastError()`.

In the following I provide an example that shows how to wrap `SetWindowPos()` into a function to bridge the gap between C-style error reporting and the C++ way of doing it by throwing and handling an exception.

**Example:**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <system_error>

// Show or hide the given window by calling SetWindowPos().
//
// \exception Reports any error by throwing std::sytem_error exception.

void MyShowWindow( HWND hwnd, bool show ) {
    DWORD flags = SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER;
    if( show )
        flags |= SWP_SHOWWINDOW;
    else
        flags |= SWP_HIDEWINDOW;

    if( !::SetWindowPos( hwnd, nullptr, 0, 0, 0, 0, flags ) ) {
        // NOTE: Call GetLastError() IMMEDIATELY when a function's return value indicates 
        // failure and it is documented that said function supports GetLastError().
        // ANY other code (be it your own or library code) before the next line must be 
        // avoided as it may invalidate the last error value.
        DWORD err = ::GetLastError();
        std::ostringstream msg;
        msg << "Could not change visibility of window (HWND 0x" << hwnd << ")";
        throw std::system_error( static_cast<int>( err ), std::system_category(), msg.str() );
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

When using the wrapper function `MyShowWindow()` you must make sure to catch the exceptions thrown by it. The following example shows how to do that.

```
int main(){
    try{
        // Passing an invalid handle to MyShowWindow() will throw
        // std::system_error exception. There may be other reasons for the
        // function to fail, for instance if you pass the window handle of  
        // another process to which you don't have access as an argument
        // to the function.
        HWND anInvalidHandle = 0;
        MyShowWindow( anInvalidHandle, true );
    }
    catch( std::system_error& e ){
        // Catch the exception thrown by MyShowWindow() and report all
        // available error details.
        // e.code() outputs the error code retrieved via GetLastError().
        std::cout << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl
                  << "Error code: " << e.code() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Error: Could not change visibility of window (HWND 0x00000000): Ung³ltiges Fensterhandle
Error code: system:1400
```

The message says "invalid window handle", the error code corresponds to ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE.

**Note:**

Although the provided `MyShowWindow()` function only supports `SW_HIDE` and `SW_SHOW` functionality of `ShowWindow`, the remaining functionality could propably be provided by using additional `SetWindowPos` flags (e. g. `SW_SHOWNA` maps to `SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOACTIVATE`) or calling other Windows API functions that provide this functionality and are documented to support `GetLastError()`.

Comment: You need to call `GetLastError` **immediately** after entering the condition, where it returns a meaningful value. Your implementation of `MyShowWindow` is dangerously close to breaking that invariant. It takes a single object with automatic storage duration, whose destructor runs in between `SetWindowPos` returning, and your call to `GetLastError`. Calling `GetLastError` seems to be the most common bug in error handling. Please don't contribute to that by posting almost incorrect code.

Comment: @IInspectable _it takes a single object with automatic storage duration, whose destructor runs_ ... Please name the object that you think has a destructor. I only see POD datatypes here which don't have a destructor by definition.

Comment: *"Your implementation [...] is dangerously **close**"*. And *"[...] by posting **almost** incorrect code."*

Comment: @IInspectable Please explain why it would still be _dangerously close_ and _almost incorrect code_ after I invalidated your original argument.

Comment: You never invalidated any of the points I made. You failed to comprehend, and invalidated something that you believe to have been there. I already explained how little it takes for your code to turn bad: A single local with automatic storage duration and non-trivial d'tor (like a critical section object).

Comment: @IInspectable Rest assured that I'm aware of the `GetLastError()` contract. Such local won't create itself. With this kind of argumentation you could argue against almost any non-trivial code because you may shoot yourself in the foot with it.

Comment: You know, you would have a point there if you could make absolutely sure, that **everyone** using your code will not ever change it in any way that breaks it. In case you don't understand this: Software changes over time. You have - without any immediate need or benefit - set up a carefully crafted trap. The fact that **you** understand the contract of `GetLastError` has no bearing. This is not about you. It is about every single future reader of this answer.

Comment: @IInspectable Well, you can only go so far to protect incompetent people from themselfes. `if( !SetWindowPos(...){ /* someone may slip in code here that resets the last error */ DWORD err = GetLastError(); }` ... so I don't see how above function makes that worse.

Comment: Your implementation is different, in that you cannot possibly know, that you have implemented a bug. Nothing in `MyShowWindow` indicates, that no code at all is allowed to execute in between calling `SetWindowPos` and returning to the caller. Your implementation needlessly set up a trap. For zero benefit. I'm afraid, I'm going to have to downvote this answer.

Comment: @IInspectable I only read complains from you, how about suggestions to make it better?

Comment: This is C++. If a function cannot deliver it's promise, it throws an exception. That allows to move the call to `GetLastError` right next to the call to `SetWindowPos`. *"I only read complains from you"* - That may be so. But it does not invalidate the fact, that I have hit on a **real** issue with your code.

Comment: @IInspectable Fact is that there is nothing wrong with this code *as is*. You argued about something that *could* be but actually isn't in the code, which is not a valid reason for downvote. This is not codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @IInspectable btw, OP didn't even tag as C++

Comment: **You** decided to write C++ code. It is your responsibility to provide proper code using your language of choice. I argued about something, that *could* **very easily** be added to your code that breaks it. And even the most competent developer would not even know that they broke it, because they cannot see the code that broke. Anyway, I have clearly stated the issues with your code. If it is *that* important to you to publish brittle code (again, for no reason or benefit), then you're going to have pay the price of -2 rep.

Answer (score 1):

[`ShowWindowAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633549(v=vs.85).aspx) while asynchronous in nature, it does however tell you if the operation was started successfully or not. Depending on what you are doing, it might be a usable alternative.